# What is the eloquent Laravel way to select all of one model that is not in another table?

Tags: php, laravel

I need help writing a function using proper Laravel syntax. I know if I was writing raw SQL I would select all rows from the draft_picks table where draft_id is equal to the current draft->id and then select all players that are not in that result set, but how is this properly done in Laravel? When a new draft is created, it also creates rows in the draft_picks table, but as the pick has not yet been made the player_id column is null. I want a function that will return all players not yet drafted. To further complicate things, I am hoping to utilize 1 function that will take in 3 parameters and provide dynamic functionality.
Imagine the following tables:

```
drafts

-id
-type

draft_picks

-id
-draft_id
-team_id
-round
-pick
-player_id

players

-id
-name
-position
-years_pro
```

The 3 parameters:

```
$draftType (Either 'rookie' or 'regular', if rookie, only select players where years_pro = 0, otherwise all players)
$searchString (Allow filtering by player name)
$position (allow filtering by player position)
```

I can probably figure out the dynamic functionality on my own, but help me get started by selecting all players that have not yet been selected for a given draft.

```
public function availablePlayers($draftType='',$searchString='',$position=''){
???
}
```

Models/Relationships:

```
Draft
public function draftPicks()
{
return $this->hasMany(DraftPick::class, 'draft_id');
}
public function players()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Player::class, 'draft_picks');
    }

DraftPick

public function draft()
{
return $this->belongsTo(Draft::class, 'draft_id');
}
public function player()
{
return $this->belongsTo(Player::class, 'player_id');
}

Player

    public function draftPicks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(DraftPick::class);
    }

    public function drafts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Draft::class, 'draft_picks');
    }
```

Comment: show how you have defined these relationships

Comment: i would check out the docs on [Querying Relationship Absence](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) (particularly the `whereDoesntHave` method)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.